# build error in VS2008/.NET 3.5 on project using ClickOnce

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

In one my VS2008 solution (used with .NET 3.5), sometimes, I get the following error when I try to rebuild one of my project:

> error MSB3188: Assembly
>   'somePath/blabla.dll' must be strong
>   signed in order to be marked as a
>   prerequisite.

Another thing to know about the project is that I use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114(VS.80).aspx) to publish it.
as said on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2(VS.80).aspx) my referenced library has the following properties :
Copy Local = False, so it shouldn't be marked as prerequisite (that's why I'm quite upset by the build error message)
Specific Version = False;

The weird thing is that this errors occurs occasionally and then disappears as if by magic.

If any ClickOnce expert (or an expert on whatever actually) could explain this strange phenomenon, it would be awesome !

Comment: Welcome to the limitations of ClickOnce. Soon you will have no hair left. I ended up writing my own.

Comment: oh dear... I have already bitten all my nails, you think I'll also lose my hairs ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem too. In my case the blabla.dll was referenced in my solution but blabla.dll was also used in another.dll which i had referenced in my project.

On checking the versions of both blabla.dll they were not the same. So i updated another.dll with the correct blabla.dll and then referenced the new another.dll in my solution. The error was gone.

In short: i was using 2 versions of blabla.dll

I hope this makes sense, if not let me know. :)

Regards,
Jacob Iedema

Answer (score 0):

Does [Strong Signed Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721340/strong-signed-assemblies) work for you?

Comment: it could but the weird thing (or another one) is that, in the "application files" message box, I don't even find my referenced dll in the list

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the dll, and is it already installed in the GAC? Does the user have it installed, or are you trying to deploy it with your application?

RobinDotNet