# I do not have Application Files dialog box in my vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I am using : Visual studio 2010 Professional Edition and developing Excel addin 2007
Where could i find the options I have there? 
Or could you tell me which edition of vs has the button?

Print screen [image]
Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't ClickOnce deploy an Excel Addin.

Comment: @vcsjones - yes, actually you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the explanation from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) it says :

When you are trying to deploy Office addin :

`Data FilesFiles with .xml, .mdb, and .mdf extensions are automatically copied to the application data directory. You cannot configure these data files by using the Application Files dialog box. To locate the data directory, use the DataDirectory property. For more information, see Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications.`

Comment: Seeing (from the screenshot) that this is an Excel Add-in... I just created one in VS2010 Ultimate, and sure enough the Applications Files button is not there. Coupled with your MSDN finding, I think we have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on your Project file and choose properties... then the Publish tab... you do not see the Application Files button there?

IIRC, ClickOnce is supported in all versions of Visual Studio... all the way down to the Express Editions.

Comment: No I dont I will post py printscreen