# Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Interop.Office' does not have a strong name

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, winforms-interop

I have a WPF 4 project  to interact with word documents made in VS2010 and a win form User Control project to host word application into it. And other com dlls. All com dlls are referred into my main wpf application. I want to publish my project so I can install it on another machine and perform automatic update for it, I get  error: "Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Interop.Office' does not have a strong name. ". error for each COM Dll. 
A dll refer to (Interop.word.dll, interop.office.dll, interop.VBIDE.dll) and all these dlls are also refer and used into my wpf code.

I found [Strong Signed Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721340/strong-signed-assemblies) link have same question but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Just remove the references and add them back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I spent a while trawling the internet for this, I believe that the answer you need may be here, for most 3rd party dll's.

["Adding Strong Name to Interop DLL"](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-strong-name-to-third-party.html)

The article describes three ways to add a strong name to a third party assembly. The commands are:
1. Adding a Strong Name via Key Pair

```
> SN -k MyKeyPair.snk
> ILDASM ASQLService.dll /out:ASQLService.il
> ILASM ASQLService.il /dll /resource=ASQLService.res /key=MyKeyPair.snk
```

2. Adding a Strong Name via a Certificate in a Certificate Store

```
> ILDASM ASQLService.dll /out:ASQLService.il  
> MAKECERT -ss MyCertificateStore -sk MyKeyContainer
> ILASM ASQLService.il /dll /resource=ASQLService.res /key=@MyKeyContainer
```

3. Adding a Strong Name via a Certificate in a Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) File

```
> MAKECERT -r -pe -sv MyCertificate.pvk MyCertificate.cer
> PVK2PFX -pvk MyCertificate.pvk -pi qwerty -spc MyCertificate.cer -pfx MyCertificate.pfx
> SN -p MyCertificate.pfx MyCertificate-publickey.snk
> ILASM ASQLService.il /dll /resource=ASQLService.res /key=MyCertificate-publickey.snk
> SN -R ASQLService.dll MyCertificate.pfx
```

Hope it helped

Comment: That article is amazing.

Answer (score 8):

This comment should be an answer:

> Actually, the "strong name" problem only STARTS if you decide to sign
>   your assembly, since then it'll require all referenced dlls to be
>   strong-name signed too

If you dont want to sign the assembly and wish to overcome this compilation error. Choose NOT to sign the assembly you are trying to build. Subsequently all the projects references wont require signing either.

Answer (score 5):

You must have a .snk

Right click on your project -> Properties and go on Signing tab -> Check Sign the assembly ->  choose new key

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually, the "strong name" problem only STARTS if you decide to sign your assembly, since then it'll require all referenced dlls to be strong-name signed too.